# I try to migrate SQL query to BigQuery, but i have a problem with IN statement into JOIN

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, migrate

I try converted sql query to google bigquery but have error in the complete statement( supposed when i use IN subquery into JOIN).

I am getting error:

> "IN subquery is not supported inside join predicate."

edit: i find the error is in this line

```
ON CL.WM_YR_WK IN (SELECT DISTINCT WM_YR_WK  FROM wmt-edw-prod.K2_WM_VM.CALENDAR_DAY  WHERE GREGORIAN_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-7*4 AND CURRENT_DATE+7*17)
```

Comment: There's not enough detail to review the SQL properly.  The general error that BQ does not support `ON x IN (SELECT ...)` is easily addressed.  It's just tough to transform the current SQL without fully qualified `table.column` references or at least all the corresponding CREATE TABLE statements.  Some of the JOIN / ON clause logic could have additional mistakes.

Comment: Here is the error ````ON CL.WM_YR_WK IN (SELECT DISTINCT WM_YR_WK 
FROM wmt-edw-prod.K2_WM_VM.CALENDAR_DAY 
WHERE GREGORIAN_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-7*4 AND CURRENT_DATE+7*17)````

Comment: There are several of these cases. The join criteria isn't clearly correct.  For instance, this specific case appears to be a kind of cross join, even though it uses LEFT JOIN.  The requirement of the overall query is necessary.